GKE kubectl configuration issue
I have created a GKE cluster version 1.26.15 with 2 nodes. Cluster is created successfully and running.
But when i logged in one of the nodes i am unable to run any kubectl commands.
 $ sudo kubectl get pods
E0607 10:27:28.734149    9753 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
E0607 10:27:28.734649    9753 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
E0607 10:27:28.736075    9753 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
E0607 10:27:28.736454    9753 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
E0607 10:27:28.737530    9753 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

Also i cannot see this file in node /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf

IME you don't directly log in to the nodes.  Get the kubeconfig file locally (for example following this GKE documentation) and run kubectl from your local machine.

@David Maze Thanks!!!! This was i am looking for.You can add it as answer
